# Does StackOverflow use Lucene for tagged searches?

Tags: search, lucene, tags, tagging

How has SO implemented the tagged search? Is it using Lucene or any other open-source search engine library for tagged searching?

What is the best way to search document (PDF, XML, HTML, MS Word) or database?

Comment: See "What was Stack Overflow built with": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749358/

Answer (score 1):

Searching tags is very different than searching text.  A tagged search is searching for an association where questions are all associated with a particular tag.  This can be implemented with a full-text engine where the tags are all appended in a single large entry, but a relational database will probably be best in this situation (assuming the tagged data is in a relational database to start with).

For searching other documents like PDF, XLS, HTML, then you need full text like Lucene.  You'll need a parser that can extract just the relevant text from each source (i.e., separate text from markup).

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, it is using Lucene.NET, though I'm not sure exactly how.  The "best" way is a whole 'nother story.

Answer (score 0):

The last time this was discussed (on the podcast) it was mentioned that Stackoverflow uses SQL Server's full-text search feature, not Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

SO doesn't use Lucene.

If you want to index documents and are running Windows, then [IFilters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx) would be my first choice.